# Hybrid apps; Electron and Meteor: Perspectives and questions

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, electron, hybrid

This is more of a request for general guidance from experienced developers than a real question, so please bear with me.

As you may have guessed, I come from web development. Lately I have been interested in developing computer assisted production management software, which I hope, will go gradually by developing modules until such a time we have enough to start building a full Enterprise resource planning software. (Forgive me if the terms are incorrect, I'm struggling a bit with english).

Hence my conundrum. Being a web developer, I'd have hoped to reutilize my skills to that end, and with the surge of hybrid apps and desktop apps based on web languages (with the likes of [Meteor](http://meteor.com) and its library [Electrify](https://github.com/arboleya/electrify)), I just can't help but wonder if these technologies are "adapted" to creating such -let's not say complex- intricate apps, hence the following questions.

1. Are these technologies mature enough for a development of this
   scale and commitement over time. I'd hate to start on them just for
   them to "fall out of fashion" and lose all traction.
2. Are they adapted for this kind of development? Compared to
   native apps -say in C# or Java, are they truly suited for, say;
   intensive database management?
3. In this endeavor I intend to recruit a small team (Who are
   primarilly coming from native dev). Is it safe to assume that the
   learning curve will not be too steep, that they'll not become
   hopelessly lost at the early stages of learning?
4. Given that these apps will have to be highly modular to allow for
   the hypothetic Entreprise resource planning software, are hybrid
   apps a viable option?
5. And the final question might seem somewhat off-topic, but given
   that these apps will be heavily reliant on forms and database
   access, aren't web technologies just not the tool of the trade in
   this case? Even when associated with libraries like React or
   Angular, form creation and validation is a pain, whereas in IDEs
   such as VS in C#, creating forms equals dragging them in a GUI fashion from the
   database; if I remember correctly.

These are roughly my interrogations. What i'm hoping here for is for you to shed an experienced light on my situation if you can, and if you have any other remarks, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Requesting opinions in SO doesn't follow site's guidelines :(

Comment: Hence the rather specific questions. I'm just trying my luck in asking further for opinions :)

Comment: I would drop it before you get downvotes. It's absolutely outside of the scope of SO, sorry

Comment: @Unforgiven, while you have some valid questions, they do not belong in this forum. I would happily answer question one for example, if you find the right platform to ask it in. Your question would be better served here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/